# How can i, in flutter scrap data from a random website on the internet and interact with it

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, mobile-development

How can i, in flutter (or other language) scrap data from a random website on the internet (like Youtube) and interact with it (Clicking on a video) and getting the content. For exemple, login on a website by inserting an email and a password and clicking on submit(All of this in the flutter app) and then getting the data of the profil and using it inside my flutter (or other) app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.